# Name for a candidate about to sign an employment contract

Tags: word-request

What I have found so far:

(1) Applicant: A person having applied for a job (e.g. filled out web-form)

(2) Candidate: An applicant the recruiter thinks might be suitable to hire, so there will be some follow-up (e.g. job interview), though that is no guarantee the candidate will become an employee of the company.

(3) Signee/Signer: A person signing something or having signed something.

Is there a name for a person between (2) and (3), who e.g. has completed an online job-interview, was seen to be suitable for hiring, got a job offer, agreed to accept and now the recruiter is waiting for the person to come to the office to sign the employment contract.

I initially considered posting this in the workplace community, but I feel it is more of a language thing.

Comment: Hi, can you include a sample sentence (as per the tag info)?

Comment: "Successful candidate"?

Comment: Yeah, they could be a *candidate* (with some adjective) or a *prospective employee* or a *(prospective) [signatory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/signatory)* (which is more common in formal contexts for a person signing something). There isn't a precise, common one-word term for the situation you describe.

Comment: Someone who does a lot of hiring at a local university tells me that their HR department uses the phrase **final candidate** to refer to the person who is being sent an offer letter, which they must sign to acknowledge the terms of employment. But I don't think there is any standard term for the person at this transitional stage in the process. They could change their mind and not accept the position if, say, their current employer makes a counteroffer, or they get a better offer from another place. So **new hire** is premature.

Comment: It's called the pre-contractual stage of employment. And a candidate has at this point become a recruit.

Comment: @StuartF IMO "Prospective" is the best answer (maybe with the additional suggestion of "provisional"); I suggest expanding to an answer. I feel like I have actually seen "prospective employee" often, and certainly "prospective students" in college admissions, and "prospective home buyers" in real estate. Conveys "They're not this yet, but they're in the process to become this."

Comment: You can be recruited by a company but not yet signed, so to speak. final candidate sounds like the last on a list.

Answer (score 1):

Tangent: In America we refer to someone who has or will sign something as a "signer", but this is not a term normally used for someone who has just taken a job. Once he takes the job he is an "employee".

That said, I don't know any term in general use for someone who has accepted an offer of employment but not yet started the job. I've heard people refer to such a person as a "new employee" or "new hire", but the same term could be used for someone who has only been working there for a short period of time. "Selected candidate" or "successful candidate" is possible, but that means the company decided on a candidate, he might have rejected the offer, or we might still be waiting for him to accept or reject. I think if you wanted to clearly express this idea it would take a long phrase, like, "the person who accepted our job offer but who hasn't started work yet".

If there's some accepted term for such a person, I haven't heard it and places where I've worked haven't used it.

Answer (score 0):

Others have posted decent answers, but keep in mind this will vary by region, in some states a verbal acceptance of a contract is legally binding!

Answer (score -1):

a **recruited candidate or recruit**, implies a contract is not yet signed by the candidate has been successful in being offered the job

[smart recruiters](https://www.smartrecruiters.com/resources/glossary/recruitment/)
[recruitment](https://www.sage.com/en-us/blog/glossary/what-is-recruitment/#:%7E:text=Recruitment%20is%20the%20process%20of,recruit%27s%20integration%20into%20the%20company.)

Comment: Oh please downvoters, spare me.